# SQL: Grouping, Count & Average

Tags: sql, sqlite

Trying an SQL question here. I have a SQLite DB (`table`):

```
 type_id value
 1       26    
 1       24
 2       30
 3       5
 3       15
```

I want to achieve the following. For each `type_id`, I would like to know the number of rows (`count`) with that `type_id` and the average `value` (`average`) of the group. In the example table I would end up with:

```
 type_id count average
 1       2     25
 2       1     30
 3       2     10
```

Any ideas? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `GROUP BY` `type_id` and take the `COUNT` and `AVG`:

```
SELECT type_id, COUNT(*) AS count, AVG(value) AS average
FROM test
GROUP BY type_id
```

Output:

```
type_id     count   average
1           2       25
2           1       30
3           2       10
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=ed039518c0e23c0a567bd38ad7469033)

Comment: That was easy XD. Thank you!